# Linking Card IO to Project from Framework (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, card.io

Using iOS, I am linking a static library set up as a framework to the core project. I have added "-all_load -ObjC" to the linker of the core project to fix a viewcontroller issue.

This has had an unintended consequence that the card.io is now not pulling through correctly. I get the following error.

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "std::terminate()", referenced from:
>       -[CardIOGPURenderer dealloc] in libflypaylib.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
>   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
>       Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libflypaylib.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
>       Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libflypaylib.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
>       Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libflypaylib.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
>       Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libflypaylib.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Is this something anyone has come across before?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Please share all your linker flags. (Are you linking with `-lc++`?)

Comment: Hey. Currently using -all_load, -ObjC. Should I add the above to this too, just as is? Cheers.

Comment: Worth a try -- cf https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/README.md#setup step 3

Answer (score 0):

Does your static library have i386 architecture slice in the binary? Just run

```
file filename
```

in the termial to see, if i386 slice is present.
Other option is to set 'build only active arch' to 'YES' and work only with device.